# How to create new sagepay account for more domain from an existing sagepay account

Tags: payment-gateway, opayo

I need to integrate sagepay to one of my website. As I am new to sagepay I have few doubts.

I have given a sagepay account details as follows(Below is just a test data)

```
https://live.sagepay.com/mysagepay/login.msp
Vendor: - **********
Username: - **********
Pass: - **********
```

In this account, It is connected to a website and has an API key for that, What I need is to create a new API credentials for my new website, I don't want to loose the existing one as it is used in some other site.

As I referred to the link https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/multiple-websites-how-many-sage-pay-accounts-do-i-need  It says that multiple account can be created with different vendor name , But I am not sure from where I can create new sagepay credentials for my new website. I have the following menus after logging in with the existing credential.

```
Administrator
Settings
AVS/CV2
3D Secure
Restrictions
Valid IPs
Change Log
Users
Pay Methods
Surcharges
Page Customiser
```

I want to know if this is the right account from where I can create more sagepay accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to sign up for a new, completely separate vendor account. Contact Sage Pay customer services.